# In Python, how can I use relative importing of a sibling file and give it a name?

Tags: python

When I have a package like:

```
somemodule/
somemodule/__init__.py
somemodule/animals.py
somemodule/cats.py
somemodule/dogs.py
```

and I'm in the `cats.py` file, can I import the entire `animals.py` file using relative importing? That is, how can I do something like (which doesn't work):

```
# in cats.py
import .animals as animals
animals.make_zoo()
```

---

I know I can do the following and cherry pick specific functions, but I don't *like* this:

```
# in cats.py
from .animals import make_zoo
make_zoo()
```

I also know I can do the following, but these do not use relative importing:

```
# in cats.py
import animals
animals.make_zoo()

# in cats.py
import somemodule.animals as animals
animals.make_zoo()
```

---

*motivation*

When I write Python code that imports code from a module, I prefer to import the entire module, rather than pluck specific functions or variables. For example:

```
# i like this:
import sys
print(sys.argv)

# i don't like this
from sys import argv
print(argv)  # where did argv come from!?!
```

My reasoning is that the module name in the symbol hints to a reader where they can find its implementation. Whether this is good is not the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `from . import animals`, or, if you want to use `as` to choose a different name `from . import animals as blah`.